# Add element to a Set from the Left (for readability)

Tags: scala

Consider adding an element (from the left) to a Sequence using `+:` :

```
scala> val cl = Seq(1,2,3)
scala> 5 +: cl
res2: Seq[Int] = List(5, 1, 2, 3)
```

What (if any) is the equivalent for a Set ?

```
scala> val s = Set(1,2,3)
scala> 5 +: s
<console>:9: error: value +: is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
              5 +: s

scala> 5.toInt + s
<console>:9: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int <and>
  (x: String)String
 cannot be applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int])
              5.toInt + s
```

**Update**  I am well aware a Set ***does not retain order***. The motivation is for **readability** of the code in certain cases - specifically when the Set is actually a long computation.  The intent is  to highlight the *new* element being added by placing it before that computation.

Comment: What is the meaning of *adding to the left* of a `Set`? Is this a general question or is there anything behind that you're trying to achieve? Because, i.e. if you had a `Set[Int] {1, 2, 3}` and `Set[Int] {2, 1, 3}`, from a mathematical perspective they are equal.

Comment: Aside - you can add an element to a `Set` via `Set(1,2,3) + 4`, per [Set#+](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set@+(elem:A):This).

Comment: As far as I know... Set is not supposed to be ordered ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most implementations of `Set` don't preserve insertion order, so it doesn't make much sense to have such an operation.
Of the immutable `Set`s only `ListSet` preserves (reverse) insertion order. So since it preserves *reverse* insertion order, `ListSet` has a "add to the left" method: the default `+` method. Yet it still doesn't have a "add to the other side" method.

If you simply want a `+:` method regardless of what it does, you can just add it as an extension method:

```
scala> implicit class PrependSet[A](val set: Set[A]) extends AnyVal {
     |   def +:(a: A) = set + a
     | }
defined class PrependSet

scala> 5 +: Set(1,2,3)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. You *can* however wrap the element in a Set and concatenate.

```
scala> Set(5) ++ Set(1,2,3)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3)
```

This will of course only work if that element isn't already contained in the set.

However, you can't depend on the ordering in these sets. Mathematically, a set is an unordered collection of unique elements and you should treat them as such. See [the documentation for sets](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html) for all the available operations on Sets. You might want to read about "Sorted sets" while you're at it.

Comment: In the OP/title: "  from the ***left*** "  -- and for an ***element*** not another Set

Comment: Concatenating two sets preserves order only until 4 elements due to implementation details

_The default implementation of an immutable set uses a representation that adapts to the number of elements of the set. An empty set is represented by just a singleton object. Sets of sizes up to four are represented by a single object that stores all elements as fields. Beyond that size, immutable sets are implemented as hash tries._

After that order is not preserved (which is expected):

`scala> Set(10) ++ Set(5, 1, 2, 3)`

`res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expect that if you add an element "on the left" of a `Set`, that element will become the first element of the `Set`, just like it works with `Seq`.

Sets in general are not ordered, and elements in a set do not have an index or position; there's no such thing as "the first element" in a `Set`. Think of a `Set` as a bag full of items. The items are not in any particular order in the bag, and when you stick your hand in and grab an item, you never know which one you get first.

You can see this in the Scala REPL when you create a `Set` with for example 7 elements:

```
scala> val s1 = Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
s1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4)
```

Note that the elements are not listed in any "logical" order.

You can use `+` to add an element to a `Set`. Just don't expect the element to be added in any particular position:

```
scala> val s2 = s1 + 8
s2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)
```